# Retrieving values triggering numpy floating point error

Tags: numpy

While `numpy.seterr` allows customization of what happens when a floating point exception happens, for example calling a specific callback, it does not seem to provide information about the specific values that triggered the exception.

Reusing one of the examples from the docs:

```
def err_handler(type, flag):
    print "Floating point error (%s), with flag %s" % (type, flag)
saved_handler = np.seterrcall(err_handler)
save_err = np.seterr(all='call')
np.array([1, 2, 3]) / 0.0

Floating point error (divide by zero), with flag 1
array([ Inf,  Inf,  Inf])
```

it would be nice if the `err_handler` callback could `print` something like:

```
Floating point error (divide by zero), with flag 1.  
Attempted operation: array([1, 2, 3]) / 0.0.
```

Any help in achieving this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use traceback to print the stack?

```
import numpy as np

def err_handler(type, flag):
    import traceback
    traceback.print_stack(limit=2)
    print "Floating point error (%s), with flag %s" % (type, flag)

saved_handler = np.seterrcall(err_handler)
save_err = np.seterr(all='call')
a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) 
b = 0.0
a / b
```

Comment: I am actually already doing this, but this doesn't provide the value or even just the names of the variables that actually caused the fp error.  (Of course I could introspect the stack and extract that information manually but I was hoping for something simpler...)

Comment: Actually the proper solution is probably to combine this with one of the numerous tb-formatting libraires now in existence (e.g. tbvaccine).